# Multi-dimensional feasible region

Tags: linear-algebra

Instead of solving the equality Ax=b, I want to solve the *inequality* Ax>=b. In general, how can I solve this problem with *n* unknowns, or when A has *n* columns?

When A has 1 column (or, when each equation in this system has only 1 unknown *x*) I can solve it easily by isolating *x* in each inequality and combining the inequalities to yield 1 inequality that bounds *x*. When choosing a satisfactory *x*, I simply refer to the yielded inequality.

When A has 2 columns (or, when each equations has 2 unknowns *x* and *y*), I graph the constraints and find the shaded regions, and use the appropriate equations for different x intervals (i.e., for *x* = 0 to *x* = 10 use *x* + *y* <= 50 and for *x* = 11 to *x* = 20 use 10 *x* +10 *y* <= 30). When choosing a satisfactory pair (*x* , *y*), I plug in *x* to the equation appropriate for the *x* interval, and I can choose any *y* value within the bounds for *y*.

However, I don't know how to handle systems with 3 or more unknowns. I'm currently learning this on my own, so if there is any or standard literature on this specific topic, links would be appreciated, as I tried googling. If this question needs more clarification, please let me know. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In 3 dimensions, the region is the intersection of three closed halfspaces. Generically, they form a triangular "pyramid without a base" (i.e., a triangular cone), but there are exceptional cases such as "triangular cylinder", if the rank of $A$ is $2$. I think your attempt to rewrite $Ax\ge b$ in a "simpler" form is not going very far in higher dimensions. You are trading one system of inequalities for another, condition-laden one.

So, my answer is: it's good that you worked through this in two-dimensional case, but do not try to make $Ax\ge b$ more "explicit" in higher dimensions: it's not going to work.